# Riverpod generator stuck on 0 actions and 0 outputs

Tags: riverpod, riverpod-generator

It's the code I used and run the command `dart pub run build_runner watch`:

```dart
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

part 'welcome_notifier.g.dart';


@riverpod
class IndexDotProvider extends _$IndexDotProvider {
  @override
  int build() {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

this is stuck here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhpzd.png).

I have installed riverpod generator, build runner, riverpod annotations packages in `pubspec.yaml`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is a `build.yaml` file in the root of your project that has incorrect settings? But most likely, you simply forgot to specify `riverpod_generator` as a dev dependency. Check the `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  # https://riverpod.dev/docs/getting_started
  riverpod:
  # the annotation package containing @riverpod
  riverpod_annotation:

dev_dependencies:
  # a tool for running code generators
  build_runner:
  # the code generator
  riverpod_generator:
```

Also, you can write like this:

```dart
@riverpod
class IndexDot extends _$IndexDot {
  @override
  int build() {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

which is the output of `indexDotProvider`.

Comment: It's still stuck after changing to Dev dependencies

Comment: maybe `flutter clean` will solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are few reasons why the class was not generated, like:

1. the name 'filename.g.dart' is not exactly equal to your file name,
2. there is a syntax error in the file
3. the class should extends _$class_name

But in your case there are no errors.
Thus the problem should be in your project file.

In my case it works with:

```
dependencies:
      flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.9
      riverpod: ^2.4.9
      riverpod_annotation: ^2.3.3
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: any
  riverpod_generator: ^2.3.9
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

And the command is:

```
dart run build_runner watch
```